# Getting exception while joining the below queries, could someone help me on joining the queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Query 1 :

```
  select col1,sum(col2) from tablea src 
  join 
  (select distinct col3,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col3 desc) as RN ) 
   From tableb) trgt
   where RN=1 and src.col3 = trgt.col3 group by col1
```

Query 2 :

```
 select col1,sum(col2) from tablea src 
 join 
 (select distinct col3,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col3 desc) as RN ) 
 From tableb) trgt
 where RN=2 and src.col3 = trgt.col3 group by col1
```

Join Query :

```
   select * 
   from (Query 1)  curr join (Query 2) 
    prev on curr.col1 = prev.col1
```

FAILED: ParseException line 6:75 cannot recognize input near 'as' 'curr' in subquery source

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to join these two queries, since they are very similar to each other like two drops of water.
Some kind of pivot query can do this job:

```
SELECT col1,
       SUM( CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN col2 END ),
       SUM( CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN col2 END )
FROM  tablea src 
JOIN (
   select col3,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col3 desc) as RN ) 
   From tableb
) trgt
ON src.col3 = trgt.col3 AND trgt.rn <= 2
GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: If you like my answer then please accent it, thank you.